# check if element is the root document inside shadow dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom

How can I check if for an element inside a shadow DOM, the element itself is the shadow root ?

I tried `if (elem===elem.getRootNode())` but this doesn't work, as one is an element and one is a Node.

What is the correct test ?

My case is that I have code a Chrome extension that climbs up the DOM tree from a given element doing `elem = elem.parentElement` until `elem===document.documentElement`.

I am now trying to extend the above test condition to work for elements inside shadow DOM. When climbing up from an element in a shadow DOM I want to end when reaching the root of the shadow DOM not the root of the entire page.

I only need a Chrome solution.

Comment: were these shadow doms created by you?

Comment: no, my code is a chrome extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elem.getRootNode()` return the root `Node` of an element. So if you are in a Shadow DOM, `elem.getRootNode()` return the `ShadowRoot` node of the element.

You can simply check if an element is a `ShadowRoot` by the type of the element.

```
elem instanceof ShadowRoot
```

Here an exemple with a function that search the root. Useless because there is getRootNode, just for demo.

```js
function findShadowRoot(element){
  if(element instanceof ShadowRoot) return element;
  if(!element.parentNode) return null;
  return findShadowRoot(element.parentNode);
}

var shadow = document.querySelector('#element-hote').attachShadow({mode: "open"});
shadow.innerHTML = '<p><span id="inner">Inner shadow text!</span></p>';
var inner = shadow.querySelector('#inner');
console.dir(inner.getRootNode().innerHTML)
console.dir(findShadowRoot(inner).innerHTML);
console.log(inner.getRootNode() == findShadowRoot(inner))
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p id="element-hote"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok great, I was hoping for a single test that will check for both elements inside and outside a shadow dom, but I guess I can do: elem===document.documentElement || elem instanceof ShadowRoot